# Create PNG image with background consisting of squares in two colors

Tags: php, image, imagecreatefrompng

i'm tring to create PNG image with background consisting of squares in two colors, the squares is repeated horizontally or vertically as in the picture.

[image]

This is my code :

```
<?php
$maxwert = 300;
$size = 20;
$img = imagecreatetruecolor($maxwert, $maxwert);
imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);

   for($y=0;$y<$maxwert;$y += $size){
     for($x=0;$x<$maxwert;$x+=$size){
      $r = rand(0,255);
      $g = rand(0,255);
      $b = rand(0,255);
      $color = imagecolorallocate($img, $r, $g, $b);
     
      imagefilledrectangle ($img, $x, $y, $x+$size ,$y+$size, $color);
    
     }
   }                 
// Save the image
imagepng($img, 'imagefilledrectangle.png');
imagedestroy($img);
?>
```

My output:

[image]

Comment: Does it work? If not, what is the output?

Comment: How are your code and image related to your question please? You said you want an image with two repeating colours, but you show an image with a black bar on the left - which do you want? You say you want an image with repeating colours and show grey and white, but your code allocates something black which you name as "red" and something you call a green rectangle but which is white and only fills one half of the image without repeating!

Comment: I have updated the code with a version closer to what I want. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two colours outside the loop and then cycle one then the other

```
<?php
$maxwert = 300;
$size = 20;
$img = imagecreatetruecolor($maxwert, $maxwert);
$colors = [
    imagecolorallocate($img, rand(0,255), rand(0,255) rand(0,255)),
    imagecolorallocate($img, rand(0,255), rand(0,255) rand(0,255))
];


for($y=0;$y<$maxwert;$y += $size){
    for($x=0;$x<$maxwert;$x+=$size){
        imagefilledrectangle ($img, $x, $y, $x+$size ,$y+$size, $colors[(($x/$size)%2+($y/$size))%2]);    
    }
}                
// Save the image
imagepng($img, 'imagefilledrectangle.png');
imagedestroy($img);
?>
```